# Last readline function was working until a recent syntax error

Tags: python, indexing, format, readline

I have a readline function that was working until I got to the last steps in my code.

In the beginning of the code I used "hammer" to define the function for reading a line off a text file.

Hammer was reused as a string several times to represent other functions in the loop.

Now when I place it at the end of the function I get a syntax error for "hammer."

(I've included the invoice.txt file contents that "hammer" grabs from right below the instructions)

```
# * Statement: Echos the contents of the file invoice.txt and sums prices and 
# * count of items
# * Specifications:
# * Input  - string describing a tool in the file invoice.txt
# *        - price of the tool in the file invoice.txt
# * Output - Message indicating the item and the cost
# *        - The sum of all costs and the number of items in the file invoice.txt
# ************************************************************************/

########################
# invoice.txt contents #
#--------------------- #
########################
hammer#9.95         
saw#20.15           
shovel#35.40

# output descriptive messages
print('This program will read each line in the file invoice.txt and print a\n'
       + 'a table indicating the item and it\'s cost.  When the file is exhausted,\n'
       + 'it will print the cumulative sum of all of the costs and the total \n'
       + 'number of items.\n')

# display header line for items list
print('{0: <10}'.format('Item'), '{0: >17}'.format('Cost'), sep = '' )

def main():

    invoice = open("Invoice.txt","r")

    count = 0
    total = 0

    hammer = invoice.readline()

    #Once hammer is read keep going
    while hammer != '':
        saw = invoice.readline()
        shovel = invoice.readline()

        #strip of extra lines
        hammer = hammer.rstrip('\n')
        saw = saw.rstrip('\n')
        shovel = shovel.rstrip('\n')

        #strip hashtags
        hammer = hammer.split('#')
        saw = saw.split('#')
        shovel = shovel.split('#')


        #print tools
        print('{0: <10}'.format(hammer[0]), '{0: >17}'.format('$' + hammer[1]), sep = '' )
        print('{0: <10}'.format(saw[0]), '{0: >17}'.format('$' + saw[1]), sep = '' )
        print('{0: <10}'.format(shovel[0]), '{0: >17}'.format('$' + shovel[1]), sep = '' )

        #convert prices to integer values
        total = total + (int(hammer[1])) + (int(saw[1])) + (int(shovel[1]))

        #print total line
        print('{0: <10}'.format('Total cost')) + ('{0: >17}'.format('{0:.2f}'.format(float(total))

        hammer = invoice.readline()

    invoice.close()

main()
```

[program solution pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFJa.png)

Comment: Check your parenthesis on the line above. They're not balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parenthesis wrong on the line above the line causing the syntax error. Change your `#print total` line to:

```
print('{0: <10}'.format('Total cost') + '{0: >17}'.format('{0:.2f}'.format(float(total))))
```

Comment: That worked I think, but now I am getting an error saying:

File "C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads\Python Work\6\Scan.py", line 54, in main
    total = total + (format(int(hammer[1]))) + (format(int(saw[1]))) + (format(int(shovel[1])))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9.95'

Comment: That line should be something like `total = total + ( int(float(hammer[1])) + int(float(saw[1])) + int(float(shovel[1]))`. `format` is only used on strings. And that is a completely different issue from the one in the question. Please open new questions for new problems.

Comment: @user294506 please accept this answer if it solved your issue.